# InvalidArgumentError: input must be 4-dimensional[8,6171,4]

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, conv-neural-network

I'm running a 2d convolution network. My input has 3 dimension however I am getting this 4-dimension error: 
[dimension error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PiyuF.png)

As you can see my input has the correct dimensions:

[correct input dimension](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hIgUR.png)

here is my code:

```
from keras import models
from keras import layers
model = models.Sequential()
model.add(layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(8,6171,4)))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))

model.add(layers.Flatten())
model.add(layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax'))
```

Why then is it asking me for 4-D when I only built a 3-D input layer?

Please help.
Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

You need to use

```
new_image = tf.expand_dims(image,0)
```

because the model expects a dataset instead of single images.

Answer (score 3):

Add an outer batch axis by passing `axis=0`, 0 is the location of the new dim (1, 416, 416, 3) if -1 will be at end

```
image_data = tf.expand_dims(image_data, axis=0)
```